# Select from one table where range is held in columns belonging to another table

Tags: oracle, join, query

I am trying to write a SELECT statement in **Oracle SQL** where I have a TABLE A with a "START" column and an "END" column which holds division numbers.

I want TABLE B to only extract those division numbers that are between columns "START" and "END" in table A

E.g

### TABLE_A

```
ID | START_DIVISION | END_DIVISION
---+----------------+--------------
1  | 01             | 03
2  | 06             | 08
3  | 09             | 09
```

### TABLE_B

```
DivisionNo | DivisionName
-----------+----------------------------
01         | London
02         | East Midlands
03         | West Midlands
04         | Yorkshire
05         | Lancashire
06         | Scotland
07         | South Wales
08         | North Wales
09         | Rep of Ireland
```

What I am after is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B 
WHERE DivisionNo BETWEEN TABLE_A.START_DIVISION and TABLE_A.END_DIVISION
```

I'm assuming a `JOIN` statement may do this but I'm not quite sure how to do this in SQL.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANSI SQL and SQL Server you would just use an INNER JOIN. I don't know whether Oracle supports this, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't... No DDL, so typing off the top of my head:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_b AS b
INNER JOIN table_a AS a ON b.DivisionNo BETWEEN a.start_division AND a.end_division
```

Comment: That will work on Oracle as well